# Send custom JMS Header with axis2

Tags: web-services, jms, apache-axis, webservice-client

We have a webservice that is used to send messages over JMS between two installations of the same application. 
We generate axis2 webservice client with axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin from our wsdl file. We are using Tibco and messages are sent through a topic.
We need to send a JMS header like bellow

```
SoapAction "Custom value"
```

Is there any solution for this?

I updated  with the value needed on Tibco side but it was sended as a property and not as a header. See bellow a fragment from the message:

```
Header={ JMSDestination={TOPIC:'topic'} ...}
Properties={"SOAPAction"={string:'our value'}}
Body={string:'message'}
```

I found also http://eai.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/tibco-l/axis2-with-jms-java-client-and-bw-server-soap-over-jms-1331763 that looked promissing but didn't worked either.

Thank you,
Boris

Comment: I assume you are consuming a SOAP over JMS Service published by Tibco Businessworks 5x? Therefore setting the SoapAction as JMS Property is correct, what makes you assume to set a "JMSHeader" (these are fixed fields and properties are used for the SoapAction).

Comment: Yes, you were right. SoapAction was correct. There was a miscommunication between our team and tibco team and we used the wrong wsdl to send messages.

Answer (score 1):

There was a miscommunication between our team and tibco team and we used the wrong wsdl to send messages. After we changed the wsdl everything went well.